# If returning wrong result when comparing integer with string

Tags: php, if-statement

Not sure if I'm not seeing something or what, but I have a simple `id` validation

```
$id = '2s2';

var_dump($id);
var_dump($id*1);
if ($id != ($id*1) || $id <= 0) {
    die('wrong id');
}
die('here?');
```

The result:

```
string '2s2' (length=3)
int 2
here?
```

It checks if `id` is the same as `id multiplied by 1` **or** if the value is zero or lower. Since, the value of `$id = '2s2;` it is not the same ( as can be seen in the dump ).

Why is this not echoing `wrong id` ?

Comment: Why are you multiplying a string? BTW everything multiplied by 1 is itself, isn't it?

Comment: When he multiplies the string by 1, it converts to an int. I'm trying to understand why 2.

Comment: @PhiterFernandes Oh, ok, sounds very dirty :)

Comment: @PhiterFernandes I'm guessing because it's either the number before or after the string `s`.

Comment: Yeah, it's the first int it runs into before it hits the string: https://3v4l.org/kurP5

Comment: mabye because PHP finds 2 as the first digit within the string

Comment: It's the number before. I did `echo intval('52s2');` and had the output `52`

Comment: If the aim is to convert it to a int, isn't it smarter to use `(int)` or some other designated method? Instead of multiplying it with 1?

Comment: yes, but the values `2` and `2s2` are not the same, so why is the IF considering it as true?

Comment: From the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php): _if you compare a number with a string or the comparison involves numerical strings, then each string is converted to a number and the comparison performed numerically_

Comment: This seems to be working but extremely strange way of checking a integer. if(int()$id>=0)  will do the validation.

Comment: @Albzi No, that will never match as you will be comparing a string to an integer and `2 !== '2'`.

Comment: Yes you're right @jeroen, I messed up! Sorry.

Comment: @putvande thank you for the explanation, although I don't understand why is each string converted to number, when converting each number to a string would make more sense :/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm guessing you multiply it by 1 to see if the `$id` is numeric. In that case you could simply:

```
if (!is_numeric($id) || $id <= 0) {
    die('wrong id');
}
```

Comment: Gah can't believe I made that mistake! Definitely an off day for me.

Answer (score 0):

When you compare two variables of different types (and do some other operations) PHP does an operation called [Type Juggling](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php). Basically it tries to convert both operands to the same type before operating on them.

In this case somewhat counter-intuitively PHP converts both operands to integers. The rule of [converting a string to integer](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.conversion) is basically "take chars from the beginning of a string until non-number found and discard the rest".

So left-hand `$id` is indeed `"2s2"` and is stripped from the non-integer part to `"2"` and then compared to the right operand. The right operand `($id*1)` essentially passes through the same process - in mathematical context PHP is forced to treat your string as if it is integer.

You can use strict comparison operator `if ($id !== ($id*1))` - that way you tell PHP you don't want type-juggling involved and the result would be as you have expected.

Also there is much easier way to test if `$id` is integer: [is_int()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-int.php) and [is_numeric()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php)